# Flex tree structure with comboboxes

Tags: apache-flex

I am needing to display a tree structure in flex, except in each node I need to display a ComboBox. This does not appear to be possible with the Tree control. Is there any built in way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: you'll need to extend the component yourself.